# Access public void in another class from MainActivity (Android)

Tags: java, android

I have two public voids in a class called Flashlight, these are:

public void turnOnFlashLight()

public void turnOffFlashLight()

How can I access these within Main Activity?

I've found many guides for using another class in MainActivity but not for accessing only a specific part (in this case I'm trying to turn the flashlight on or off).

This is he contents of MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    httpserver();

public void httpserver() {
    AsyncHttpServer server = new AsyncHttpServer();
    java.util.List<WebSocket> _sockets = new java.util.ArrayList<WebSocket>();
    server.listen(5000);
    server.get("/flashon", new HttpServerRequestCallback() {
        static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 0;
        public void onRequest(AsyncHttpServerRequest request, AsyncHttpServerResponse response) {
            response.send("Ok");
            Flashlight.turnOnFlashLight();

        }
    });
}
}
```

This is the Flashlight class https://stackoverflow.com/a/31289731/6696740

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: nbryans, sure I've posted a link to the Flashlight code. At this point the second answer doesn't quite work "Context in Flashlight cannot be applied to ()".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that class is imported in MainActivity. You should be able to just use **Flashlight.turnOnFlashLight()** or **Flashlight.turnOffFlashLight(**).  You might also want to create an instance of the Flashlight class like **Flashlight flashlight = Flashlight.newInstance()**, then flashlight.turnOnFlashLight() or Flashlight.turnOffFlashLight().

Comment: wow that was quick, thank you! How could do this if the class is not and cannot be set to static? I get "Cannot be referenced from a static context".

Comment: This is the Flashlight class code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31289731/6696740 this is where I am trying to use it in MainActivity             public void onRequest(AsyncHttpServerRequest request, AsyncHttpServerResponse response) {
                response.send("Ok");
                Flashlight.turnOnFlashLight();

            }

Comment: Can you post your MainActivity.java?

Comment: You cannot simply write 'Flashlight.turnOnFlashLight()' because methods are not market as static.

Comment: I've added the contents of main activity (excluding the imports) in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

In MainActivity (Assuming FlashLight class constructor does not need any input):

```
import Flashlight;
...
//where you need to call those methods
Flashlight flashLight = new Flashlight();
flashlight.turnOnFlashLight();
//OR
flashlight.turnOffFlashLight();
```

Comment: I think as you suggest it does need input, I'm not sure, "Context in Flashlight cannot be applied to ()"

Comment: this is the Flashlight class http://stackoverflow.com/a/31289731/6696740