# can't access camera parameters as the class is deprecated

Tags: java, android, camera, flashlight

it  may look like duplicate question but there is no code available to access camera or flashlight. whatever code available is old camera(android.hardware.Camera) class which is deprecated now.there is no new code for accessing the new camera class(android.hardware.camera2).so if anyone can help,it would be of great help for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27420594/115145

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 5, camera2 use only flash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420594/android-5-camera2-use-only-flash)

Comment: i used " Android5, camera2 use only flash" code but there is a problem with that. in my log it shows this "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice.close()' on a null object reference". i can't understand the error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance as you say but I think the old code will work and you are facing issues because of Android runtime permission from Marshmallow and above.

Try using runtime permission and tell if the error occurs.